# Mezonos ?  Bread 

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, bread

Is there such a thing as Mezonos bread?

Comment: I LOVE the way you wrote that!!!!!!!

Comment: See also: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/3682/what-is-mazonot

Comment: Yes if it exceptionally sweet (see Or Lesion vol. 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is much controversy on the legitimacy of Mezonos "bread". Both Rabbi Pinchos Bodner and Rabbi Forst discuss this topic at length in their books (Halachos of Brochos and Laws of B'rachos, respectively). The latter seems to conclude along the lines of jutky's answer, but there are various qualifications that the ingredients of the bread must meet... CYLOR.

On a lighter note: there's [Mandelbread](http://www.brochos.com/item/12536), [Rice Bread](http://www.brochos.com/item/30523) (made only with rice - not wheat, etc.), and possibly others, which only require Mezonos.

Comment: Not to mention sweetbread which is a straight Shehakol

Comment: Bread is by definition not Mezonot, so I'm editing your question to move the scare quotes to 'bread' instead of 'Mezonos'

Comment: @avi okay. but it's my answer

Comment: right, I meant your answer, not your question :)  More of a grammar thing than anything else.

Answer (score 6):

Sefardim make a mezonos on matzoh (except on Pesach) which is considered bread by Ashkenazim (and Sefardim on Pesach). So there you have it: Mezonos? Bread.

Comment: They do not consider it bread. They have a whole reason why you can make Hamotzi on Pesach on it.

Comment: Gershon, give us a source.

Comment: @gers he is right.

Comment: Okay, it's not that simple! HaGaon HaRav Yaakov Peretz Shelit"a holds to make Hamotzi as well as many others.

Answer (score 5):

When you get a meal on the plane there is sometimes a "mezonos" sticker on the roll.

But  you should really make a "mezonos" if you eat just the roll itself without other things, but since there you also eat garnish some poskim say you make a "המוציא" on the roll.

Comment: to add to jutky's answer and to make yitzi moses happy. the alter rebbe says that if you are making a meal out of mezonos, u should wash

Comment: This does not answer the question.  See [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15651/773) question.

Comment: @wizlog I think it does. The question asks if there there are "breads" that one makes mezonos on. The answer says that some airline meals contain such bread.

Comment: @HodofHod: I don't doubt that he answered the question, he did.  I just think that [julky](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/205/jutky) went on to ask a question afterwards.

Comment: @wizlog It doesn't clear to me, *what* question I went to ask afterwards?

Comment: this is only really what the question was based on, the one who asked obviously knew its a matter of debate, and was probably looking for sources, and/or who holds what, and the like.

Answer (score 5):

With regards to mzonos in general, The Alter Rebbe writes in Hilchos Birckas Hanehenin ([in the Siddur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&st=&pgnum=719)) it says:

1) If he eats less than 4 eggs and is full, wash on other bread.

2) If he eats less than 6 eggs, then if he is not full, one could say a mzonos. If he is full, he must say a bracha on this bread.

3) If he eats 6 eggs to half an Isarron, and he is not full, one must wash on other bread,

4) More than half an Issaron, one must wash on this bread alone.

The judgement of "is one full" on this bread includes condiment (like) the meat and eggs one eats with this bread.

Therefore, unless you eat less than 4 eggs, and you are not full from it, you gain nothing (and may have to wash on other bread).

6 eggs is around 12 ounces according to A"Ch Noeh.

Comment: So if I'm snacking on hamotzi bread and don't get full I don't have to wash, say mezonos, and al hamichya?

Comment: @larry909 You always have to wash on Hamotzi bread. Whether you say a Bracha on washing is a different question.

Answer (score 5):

There's a great story involving [R' Aharon Lichtenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Lichtenstein) on an El-Al flight trying to get a permanent cup (which is a subject for another post) to wash his hands to eat his meal, which contained a "Mezonos roll".  The flight attendant told him he didn't need to wash, and when he managed to obtain a cup and started washing, the same flight attendant adamantly insisted he really didn't need to wash and said, "If you don't believe me, ask a rabbi!"

Answer (score 2):

Many Rabbanim don't like the idea of 'Mezonos bread' calling it a contradiction in terms.

See http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/mezonos-bread.html

> Many quote the Da’as Torah (168:7) as allowing one to recite mezonos (and not having to wash and bentsch) even if one can’t taste the juice, providing that the main ingredient is juice, etc. R’ Yisroel Belsky points out that one can’t rely on this as he was referring to specific ingredients no longer used in baking.