# Do Hashgachos endorse non-proximate halachic claims on label?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification

Sometimes I find products (under Hashgacha) with halachic information written on the wrapper (away from the hechsher).

For example:

1. Some products claim "Pas Yisrael", "Chalav Yisrael" or "Yashan".
2. Some products write the Brocha to say on the product.

Does the Hashgacha organization approve these statements, or do they just claim to certify claims written in proximity to the symbol of their supervision?

Comment: Duplicate of the combination http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26575 + http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9798

Comment: @msh210 The issue of which Bracha to say is not currently mentioned explicitly in your question or answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's in yydl's question.