# What are Brochos differences of Sefardim and Ashkenazim?

Tags: food, blessing, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi

For example, according to sefardim the bracha on matzo is mezonos (during the year), while it's hamotzi for Ashkenazim.

What are other differences between Ashkenazim and Sefardim with regards to Hilchos Brochos?

**Oops:** I forgot to mention that I was referring to Brochos related to food.

Comment: yydl: will you accept differences in the nussach haberachot for food berachot?

Comment: @DoubleAA No. I'm really interested in cases like the example I gave (matzo)

Comment: Fair enough.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: There's always, of course, הַגֶּפֶן and הַגָּפֶן

Comment: @ba and נִהְיֶה vs נִהְיָה

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't think that distinction was so universally distinct among Ashkenazim and Sefardim, see [Be'er Heitev and Sha'arei Teshuvah 204:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=221)

Answer (score 5):

*This answer is to [an earlier version](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/10094/1) of the question.*

During *havdala*, *Ashk'nazim* say *bore mine b'samim* no matter what they smell ([*MB* 297:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&st=&pgnum=145&hilite=)), whereas *S'faradim* say the appropriate *b'racha* for the particular thing they smell ([*Kaf Hachayim* 297:31](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14421&st=&pgnum=177&hilite=)).

Answer (score 4):

*This answer is to [an earlier version](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/10094/1) of the question.*

Sefardim say a different bracha on Torah and Hallel ("al divrei torah"). Also, the women do not say brachos on mitzvos they're not obligated in.

Answer (score 1):

**1. (Cooked) Rice**

*Ashkenazim:* A G-d fearing Jew will only eat rice within a meal. If he has no bread - he should say Shehakol. (Kitzur Sh.A 52:17)

*Sefardim* say Borei minei Mezonot on cooked rice. (Ben Ish Hai: Pinchas 17 [First year])

**2. (Diluted) Wine**

*Askkenazim* would say Borei Pri Hagafen as long as there is more than 1 part wine to 6 parts water && people are accustomed to drink their wine diluted to that extent. (Kitzur SH.A. 49:3)

*Sefardim* would say Borei Pri Hagefen only if their is a *majority wine over water*, && the mixture tastes like wine. (See Kaf Chaim 204 S.K. 31,33)

**3. Sweet Bread/Challah**

Flour which is kneaded with oil/honey/milk/egg/fruit juice **but the majority of the liquid is still water** (even though you can taste [the sweetness of] the friut juice(say)):

*Ashkenazim* would hold that this is considered bread (and does not have the status of Pat Haba-ah B'Kisnin) - so you would say Hamotzie on it. (see Kitzur Sh.A. 48:2]

*Sefardim* hold that as long as you can taste the fruit juice a little - it's Mezonot.
(S.A 168:17)

[This, by the way was probably what @AdamMoshe was referring to in his answer]

NB: For all above I have used the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch with Piskei R. Mordechai Eliahu.

Comment: Except Aruch Hashulchan (208:21) and Mishna Berura (208:25) rule to say Mezonot on rice. And your conclusion about diluted wine is far from agreed upon, see http://revach.net/tefila/article.php?id=4065&style=print

Comment: As I stated in my answer - I was just quoting the notes brought in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch with Piskei R. Mordechai Eliahu.. if you have that book - you could see it for yourself

Comment: I believe you, but this seems more like an answer about differences between the Kitzur and the Ben Ish Chai than one about Sephardim vs Ashkenazim.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the bread rolls distributed on airplanes that are (possibly incorrectly) labeled as *mezonos*:

- Sephardim may recite *Borei Minei Mezonot*
- Ashkenazim should recite *Ha-motzi Lechem Min Ha-aretz*

Comment: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3248/732

Comment: AdamMosheh: can you source this sweeping statement?

Comment: The same is true for bagels. I'll try to look up sources later but this has to do with what constitutes motzi v. mezonot. In essence, it has to do with what % (any, or >50%) of a food is breadlike.