# What are Brochos seforim for Sefardim?

Tags: food, blessing, books-generally, product-recommendation, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

There are many Hilchos Brochos (**on food**) seforim for Ashkenazim such as [Halachos of Brochos](http://www.feldheim.com/halachos-of-brochos.html), [The Laws of B'rachos](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/lobh.html), etc.

What are examples of English Brachos seforim that sefardim could use? (in other words, seforim that follow sefardi psak)

---

Obviously, the premise of this question is highly related to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10094/what-are-brochos-differences-of-sefardim-and-ashkenazim) (which has yet to get an answer)...

Comment: I assume you mean modern ones that address modern food-production techniques, as opposed to things like _Kaf Hachayim_ and _[Hapardes](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/16250)_ and _Ben Ish Chay_?

Comment: @msh210 Yes, you are correct. Similar to the examples I gave (i.e. that have comprehensive coverage)

Answer (score 5):

[Birchot Eliyahu](http://www.nehora.com/birkhoth-eliyahu-guide-laws-of-blessing/) by Yedidi Rabbi Eliyahu Yahud Shalita

Answer (score 1):

User [Deuteronomy](http://www.reddit.com/user/Deuteronomy) on [/r/Judaism](http://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/) [suggested](http://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/kyyz3/any_sefaradim_out_there_who_can_answer_this/c2oesgv) the volume of [Yalkut Yosef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yalkut_Yosef) on Brachot.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question, judging by the comment exchange.

Comment: @SethJ, I'm not sure what you mean. The only comments (presently) are a side discussion about the Yalkut Yosef in general. I don't see anything that either further supports or challenges the Brachot volume's utility as a contemporary Sefaradic book on the laws of brachot.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the comments on our question above. He is looking for a modern book that deals with consumer products as well as general foods.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Well I haven't taken a look at it yet, but I doubt it has a list of actual foods. Probably more or less rules.

Answer (score 1):

Birkhot Shamayim by Rabbi Yosef Dweck provides an index of what Berachot to make on which foods, and the Sephardi laws of Berakhot.