# What Bracha do we say on bread baked with evaporated mei peiros?

Tags: halacha, blessing, technology, water, fruits

If one bakes bread made out of flour and pure fruit juice, it becomes pas haba bekisnin and the bracha is (at times) mezonos.

What if one distilled fruit juice (to produce water) and baked bread out of it and flour. Is the resulting considered bread or pas haba bekisnin?

---

What if one used a centrifugal distilator to produce water from mei peiros, does this water stay mei peiros or become water with regards to brachos?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3248/mezonos-bread

Comment: This question can be generalized a lot: 1) There are many other dinim of water which are deoraita, such as hechsher tumah, nissuch hamayim, mikva. 2) Just go out and ask how to understand Chazal's categorizing juices etc. not as water when we know it's basically just water and sugar. Then, we can better understand if/when/how we can revert back to having it be water.

Comment: @DoubleAA I had another question regarding dew and the difference between it and regular water

Comment: @DoubleAA You can mix glacial acetic acid and sodium bicarbonate (both are solids) and make water with sodium acetate (non toxic). I wonder if that is kosher when water is needed.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin See Magen Avraham 168 somewhere around sif katan 15 - he says fruit juice does not make pas haba bkisanin.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that pas haba b'kisanin is not a hamotzi is because it is made in such a way that it is not eaten as bread ([Beis Yosef 168 s.v. ומה](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=283&hilite=)), even though it still *is* bread ([Rambam Hil. Berachos 3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2503.htm):9, although Taz 168:10 implies otherwise).  Something which is added in but does not remove the bread from being eaten as normal bread does not create this halacha, resulting in the following dispute:

The Mechaber and the Rema have a dispute how strongly the fruit juice (or anything kneaded into the dough) needs to be tasted in order to give it the halacha of pas haba b'kisanin - the Rema holds that it must be strongly tasted, and the Mechaber holds it only needs to be discernible ([O.C. 168:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=548)).  Whether or not water distilled from fruit juice would be considered fruit juice for other halachos, it would not even meet the lower standard required by the Mechaber, as it tastes like water.

Therefore, this bread would be normal bread.

The [Magen Avraham 168:16](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=549&hilite=) understands the opinion of the Rambam to be that fruit juice never makes pas haba b'kisanin.