# Bread with fruit baked into it

Tags: halacha, blessing, bread, mezonot-beracha, hamotzi-beracha

What would be the bracha on "bread" that had mashed fruit or vegetable kneaded into the dough, but tastes like bread? For example, if you mashed a few potatoes into the dough, then the bread will still look and taste very much like regular bread after it's done. Is using mashed fruits/vegetables different than [making bread out of fruit juices](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26927/what-bracha-do-we-say-on-bread-baked-with-evaporated-mei-peiros/36668#36668)?

<sup>(Note: the link above is to an answer because the question was not about fruit juices in general, but the answer is)</sup>

Comment: According to Ashkenazim or Sephardim?

Comment: @Scimonster both, preferably. Odddly/annoyingly, so many of the "bread-like food" questions on the site are answered only according to one side

Comment: @Matt But not the answer you linked to!

Comment: @YeZ ah, oops sorry I hope you weren't insulted

Comment: @Matt Not at all.  I plan on answering this question tonight or tomorrow afternoon if I have time.

Comment: We have bread baked with raisins in it on Purim and it is still Hamotzi.

Comment: @Matt I'm drafting an answer, and want to make sure I am not barking up the wrong tree.  Can you clarify why you think this case should be different than the referenced case of fruit juice?  Is it the liquid/solid distinction?

Comment: @YeZ yes, that's the only reason (that I can think of) that would make it different. Normally, bread with fruit in it is mezonos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are mixing in a solid instead of a liquid.  There are two reasons why this doesn't make a difference.  The first is that one of the examples cited of things mixed in is spices, which are not a liquid and are not being substituted as a binding agent of the dough, and even so they have the same status as fruit juices ([Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 168:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x983)).  Secondly, this case seems analogous to the halacha of bread made from flour of the 5 grains mixed with flour of legumes or beans, discussed in [Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 208:9](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1032).  In that halacha, the Mechaber states that as long as it still has the taste of the grain it still gets Hamotzi.

This is not the same as fruit fillings (discussed in 168:7) for several reasons, but the simplest reason is that fruit fillings alter the way in which the bread is eaten, making it into a snack-ish food (see Magen Avraham 168:35), whereas your example of non-taste-altering additions would not.

Additionally, the Nesivos in his introduction to his Maaseh Nisim Hagada, in the section about hamotzi, says that all of the reasons for pas haba b'kisanin are just examples of things that would turn the bread into something eaten as a snack, and any bread item would depend on that factor alone.  If your bread feels, looks, and tastes like bread, then it would be in the Nesivos' category of non-pas haba b'kisanin.

Comment: I'd give you an extra +1 if I could for the Maaseh Nisim. A friend of mine used it to introduce a halacha shiur but I've never heard it quoted otherwise

Comment: @Matt and they left it out of the newer printing of Maaseh Nisim!  Chutzpah!

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing about the "mashed fruit" process, this sounds like the way date bread is made. According to [this list](http://ou.org.s3.amazonaws.com/publications/brachot/default.htm), The bracha is *mezonot*. Banana and zucchini breads are made in a similar fashion. In both cases, dough is the main ingredient and banana or zucchini "mash" is mixed into the dough. Often things that are called "bread" in English or in recipes are actually cakes.

If this is **not** the method used to make the bread you are describing, e.g. a challah that has a few chocolate chips studded into it, then the bracha is hamotzi.

See the "disclaimer" at the top of the linked article that seems to imply (according to my understanding) that there is no such thing as "mezonot bread" if eating it as part of a meal.

Comment: Date bread has a very distinctive date taste to it, though. This doesn't